# Is there a more efficient way of combining data into a list?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

For some background, I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and I am obtaining data from two ADXL345's. No issue there. Right now, the code is like this:

```
x1, y1, z1 = accel1.read()
x2, y2, z2 = accel2.read()
coordinates.append([x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, time.time()])
```

However, I want to figure out if it is possible to combine all of those statements into a single line along the lines of this, more or less:

```
coordinates = [accel1.read(), accel2.read, time.time()]
```

One thing to note is that `accel1` or `accel2` output the data in a format like this: `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`. I have tried this but it gives an error. Is there a way to streamline this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just unpack them using `*` operator:

```
def read():
    return 1, 2, 3

lst = [*read()]

print(lst) # output [1, 2, 3]
```